# TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of null

Tags: node.js, express, server

I'm hosting a time table website for a high school but since 2 days every time someone searches his time table the node server shuts down and gives this error

```
'value' : element.match(/.*rooster|t\/m|\d\d\s\w{3}/gi).join(' ').slice(1).toLowerCase(),
                                                               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of null
    at scheduleNames (/home/rooster/production/schedule.js:63:64)
    at toJSON (/home/rooster/production/schedule.js:78:15)
    at IncomingMessage.res.on (/home/rooster/production/schedule.js:46:34)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:934:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

There is an error in this bit of code but I don't know what it is:

```
'value' : element.match(/.*rooster|t\/m|\d\d\s\w{3}/gi).join(' ').slice(1).toLowerCase(),
```

Comment: Your `regex` not working properly it returns `null` value. check your values with that `rackets` is that matched

Comment: First you should enclose that line of code in try catch block . and secondly you should make null check before you join by space.